# Angular/Power BI Embedding

Tags: angular, azure, powerbi

When trying to reach the Power BI api via Angular front and an Azure app registration, I get this error after authenticating to my app registration and then trying to reach the Power BI api.

In Angular, I am using MSAL

```
GET https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

[image: error]

In my app registration’s authentication tabs, I have:

1. A single-page application Redirect URL
   [image: doc]
2. I have “Enable the following mobile and desktop flows” set to Yes
   I have the correct API settings for the Power BI with the stats of “Granted”.
   I have also verified that I have the correct client Id, tenant Id and client secret.
   When I do an http.get to “https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups//reports/” I get an unauthorized response. I think there could be a token I need to pass to authenticate that, but not sure where to get that token from.

I created a .Net Framework MVC project with this same set up and I can get the Power BI API thru the same Azure App registration. Which confuses me more why the Azure app works one way, but not another.

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate using a client secret from a browser app?  It's only safe to have the user authenticate themselves from a browser.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to authenticate using a client secret from a browser. We will eventually embed the PBIs into another application where the authentication has to happen "behind the scenes"

Comment: I’m not sure why it’s not working, but that’s a totally insecure.  The client secret should never be sent to a browser.